# how to pass dynamic parameter in the REST API url using golang

Tags: rest, go

I am getting the encoded url from postman (google api). In the url, I have the query written to fetch info from a db. In the query, I have hardcoded the date parameter for which I want to fetch the data. But when I am using the encoded query in my code (written in golang), I want the date parameter to be coming from a variable which should be changing on daily basis. But in no way I am able to pass this dynamic variable in the url. Any help on this?

Code snippet:

```
https://*************/?q='Last Date' >= "09/04/2018 12:00:00 AM " and 'Last Date' <= "10/04/2018 11:59:59 PM"&fields=values(ID, Name)
```

This is the url I'm using in postman and I am getting an encoded url in return something like this:

```
"https://*************************/?q=Last%20Date'%20%3E%3D%20%2209%2F04%2F2018%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM%20%22%20and%20'Last%20Date'%20%3C%3D%20%2210%2F04%2F2018%2011%3A59%3A59%20PM%22&fields=values(ID%2CName)
```

In place of Last Date (which is hard coded in url), I am trying to use a variable which has the dates coming from somewhere else (dynamic variable), something like this:

```
i:= RunDate.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
```

I want to add 'i' in place of Last Date in the query, but by doing so, it's throwing error

Comment: Please include code snippet.

Comment: Added dummy code snippet

Comment: Not dummy code line. Running code - preferably a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time` package to create your date programmatically and format it for your query.

To do that, you can use [`time.Format()`](https://godoc.org/time#Time.Format). For example to get your time in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` you can use the format string "2006-01-02 15:04:05" as the parameter to `time.Format`.

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

Will output

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00
```

See the documentation of the [time](https://godoc.org/time) library

Comment: I have updated my question..could you please have a look at it?